# Can sum of two random variables be uniformly distributed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Say $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables where $X\in [-\alpha,\alpha]$, $Y\in [-\alpha,\alpha]$ and $Z=X+Y$. Is it possible to find two independent random variables with certain pdf (not necessarily identically distributed) that force $Z$ to be uniformly distributed (i.e. $Z\sim \mathcal{U}[-2\alpha,2\alpha]$)?

As the sum of $N$ random variables with zero mean resembles Gaussian distribution with zero mean, I suspect it is not possible to find two such random variables. Do you know any counterexample?

Comment: Very rough sketch of argument: We can conclude that $P(|Z|>2\alpha-\epsilon) >0$ for every $2\alpha>\epsilon>0$, from which it follows that both $X$ and $Y$ have positive probability densities near the endpoints, but then $Z$ will more likely be $0$ than $\pm 2\alpha$...

Comment: No, the sum $Z$ of two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ cannot be uniformly distributed on an interval. The density function of a uniformly distributed random variable is discontinuous at the end points of the interval.  However, the density of $Z$ is the _convolution_ of the densities of $X$ and $Y$, $$f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)\,\mathrm dx$$ and is a continuous function of $z$ (though not necessarily a differentiable function of $z$) for all $z$.

Comment: The arguments in the previous comments apply when X and Y both have densities. Are you requiring this?

Comment: @Did I was assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with density functions and not taking the OP's statement "$X \in \{-\alpha, \alpha\}$" literally but rather as typographical errors; assuming that the OP meant to write "$X\in [-\alpha,\alpha]$"

Comment: @DilipSarwate I got that, and I agree that $X,Y\in\{-\alpha,\alpha\}$ makes little sense and should read $X,Y\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$. But my question to the OP is different--hence let us wait a reaction.

Comment: sorry for the mistake/typo. yes, $X,Y\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$. the only requirement is that $Z$ is uniformly distributed and  $Z\in[-2\alpha,2\alpha]$ is continuous. I have freedom to choose $X$ and $Y$ where $X,Y\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$.

Comment: To be sure, you do not require that $X$ and $Y$ have a density, only that they are independent and both with support in $[-\alpha,\alpha]$, right?

Comment: @Did Yes. thats right

Answer (score 11):

Here is another one.

Recall if $U_n$ are IID with Bernoulli distribution
$$
\mathbb P[U_n=0]=\frac{1}{2},\qquad 
\mathbb P[U_n=1]=\frac{1}{2},
$$
then
$$Z = \sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n 2^{-n}
$$
is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.  So let
$$
X = \sum_{n\text{ even}} U_n 2^{-n},\qquad
Y = \sum_{n\text{ odd}} U_n 2^{-n}
$$
to get independent $X,Y$ with $X+Y=Z$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $ X \sim {\mathcal U}[-\alpha, \alpha] $ and let $ Y $ be a discrete r.v. taking values $ \pm\alpha $ with equal probabilities. Then $ X+Y \sim {\mathcal U}[-2\alpha, 2\alpha] $.

I believe that the sum of $ n \geq 3 $ independent r.v.'s distributed on $ [-\alpha, \alpha] $ cannot be uniform on $ [-n\alpha, n\alpha] $, but I have no proof of this.